# Check for a single consecutive character in an array

Tags: javascript, logic

I have an array of numbers which can be a value of either `1` or `0`.
I need to create a function that detects if there is **one instance** where there is a consecutive `1` and no other `1` exist outside of that instance, returns `true` else `false`

So to sum it up here's a clearer view of the constraints to return `true`:

1. must have ***only one set*** of consecutive `1`
2. there must be no other `1` outside of that one instance of consecutive `1`

Test cases:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] true

[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] false

[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] false

[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0] false

[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] true

[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1] true
```

Comment: That's a fine problem statement. What is your intuition on how to solve it?

Comment: I'm thinking of reducing the array, check if it has found a `1`, once it does, it will flag that it started to detect the `1`.

Once that flag is detected, it will continue to check for more `1`s. If there are more than one `1` already and it has detected a `0` and has detected another `1`, then it returns `false`, otherwise `true`.

My problem is with that in mind `[0, 0, 1, 1]` would be incorrect since it hasn't detected a `0` yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function hasOneRun(arr) {
  let switches = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    switches += arr[i] ^ arr[i-1];
    if (switches > 2) return false;
  }
  return switches > 0;
}
```

Counts how many times it switches from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. `arr[i] ^ arr[i-1]` is 1 only if the value changes from the previous value. If `switches` is 0 at the end, there were only 0s, so false. If it's greater than 2, then it switched to 1, then to 0, then back to 1, so there were too many runs.

Here's a fun one-liner :D

```
Math.ceil(arr.reduce((switches, val, i) => switches + (val ^ arr[i-1]))/2) === 1;
```

Edit: Some other ideas

```
const startOne = (el, i, arr) => el == 1 && arr[i-1] != 1;
const is1 = x => x === 1;

arr.filter(startOne).length == 1;
arr.findIndex(startOne) === arr.findLastIndex(startOne);
arr.slice(arr.findIndex(is1), arr.findLastIndex(is1)+1).every(is1)


/^0*1+0*$/.test(arr.join('')); // zero or more zeroes, one or more ones
```

Or if you treat it as a sequence of bits…

```
function hasOneRun(x) {
  while (!(x&1)) x >>= 1; // shift off trailing zeroes
  return (x&(x+1)) === 0; // see if one less than power of 2 (all 1s)
}
console.log(hasOneRun(0b001111000));
console.log(hasOneRun(0b11000));
console.log(hasOneRun(0b1111));
console.log(hasOneRun(0b1110000111000));
```

Comment: for some reason this works, can you please expound what `^` does? I have no idea what it is

Comment: Exclusive or (xor).  0 ^ 0 == 0, 0 ^ 1 == 1, 1 ^ 0 == 1, 1 ^ 1 == 0. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR

Comment: You could also write `if (arr[i] != (arr[i-1] ?? 0)) ++switches;`

Comment: thanks! that is so much easier to digest.

Comment: Your one-liner fails for the test cases `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]` and `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]`

Comment: @AndrewParks Forgot to divide by 2 first. I think it's fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this by treating it as a string, and splitting it up where there are any sequences of zeroes:

```js
const testCases = [
  [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], true],
  [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], false],
  [[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], false],
  [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], false],
  [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], true],
  [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], true]
];
const f = a => a.join('').split(/0+/).filter(i=>i).length===1;
testCases.forEach(t=>console.log(f(t[0])===t[1] ? 'pass' : 'fail'));
```

Comment: sweet, this is also a nice way to solve the problem, thanks you are brilliant.

Comment: If it's a string, regex does nicely. `/^0*1+0*$/.test(arr.join(''))`

Comment: @TrevorDixon very nice!